# How to select value from JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to select a variable from an array (at least I think it's stored as an array):

```
$data = json_encode($response);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $data);
```

gives

```
"status":200,"response":{

"api_id":"0f42d6be-8ed2-11e3-822e-22135",
"bill_duration":36,
"call_duration":36,
"total_rate":"0.00300"}

}
```

How can I select the `call_duration` value (in php)? I've tried `$response['call_duration']`, which I thought should work but returns nothing?

Comment: That's a JSON object.

Comment: I don't know about php, but if the response has JSON in it, I could do something like var object = JSON.parse(response) and access your property like object.call_duration

Comment: You guys are looking too far into this.  He already had a php array called $response.  Then converted it to json and put it in a file to examine it.  The question asks how to get the value of call_duraton, which is trivial:  $response['response']['call_duration']

Comment: What happens when you do `print_r($response)`. That is usually the cleanest way to find out how to access elements from the structure.

Comment: @DanielHoward yes - I realized this before you posted your comment. You have it right, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$response['call_duration']` was very nearly correct, but I think you need:

`$response['response']['call_duration']`

Looking at your output after converting to json, I think the original array, `$response`, looks like this (in PHP array format)

```
$response = array(
  'status'=>200,
  'response'=>array(
    'api_id'=>'0f....etc',
    'bill_duration'=>36,
     ... etc
  )
);
```

So, you need to go an extra level deep into the array to get `call_duration`.